# Constructing matrix from columns of orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've got a orthogonal matrix $Q \in R^{n \times n}$. Now I'm taking the first $p$ columns from that matrix to form a matrix $Q_{f} \in R^{n\times p}$.

Now it seems to hold that:

$Q_{f}^{T}Q_{f} = I_{p}$ but $Q_{f}Q_{f}^{T} \neq I_{p}$.

I wonder why exactly that is. If it's helpful the context is that $Q$ comes from the QR decomposition of a matrix $X \in R^{n\times n}$ such that:

$X = QR_{1} = Q_{f}R$ where $R_{1}$ is an upper triangular matrix augmented with zeroes (I don't know how to typeset that).

Thanks!

Comment: Write out the individual vector products that comprise the matrix product and all will be clear.

Comment: If you only wonder why the second product doesn't give you $I_p$, the reason is simply because $Q_f$ is not square (when $n \ne p$). $Q_fQ_f^T$ can never be equal to $I_p$ because $Q_fQ_f^T$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix.

Comment: Thanks Tunococ that part makes sense. What I'm specifically interested in is why one gives the identity matrix (p x p) and the other one does not (n x n). Is this because I've constructed $Q_{f}$ from the columns of an orthogonal matrix?